# How to use Basic Authentication with jquery and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, authentication

I'm trying to load an ipcamera image to my website and the ip camera has its own javascript to load the images every second. The problem here is I am asked to login everytime i visit the page.

So far ive tried this method: http://username:password@samplewebsite.com. This works only on firefox but doesnt work on chrome and other browsers. So how can i implement a method that would allow all browsers to view this page without logging in?

The ipcamera javascript is as follows:

```
function startonload()
{
img.src = "http://username:password@samplewebsite.com/tmpfs/auto.jpg?" + (new Date()).getTime();
img.onerror=takeError;
img.onload=update;
}
```

I've heard of ways to do the html authentication with ajax and jquery. But i have no clue on how to do it.

Comment: Why would you expose password info on the net?

Comment: Any other way to do it other then that way?

Comment: server-side and pass on a session

Comment: Any examples i can use?

Comment: If you're using PHP as your server-side language, for example, you can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). I'm not writing you a full code though. Try it yourself and come back if you get stuck.